# Unable to Access Java Object From Core Module Class LibGDX Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm trying to create an Android project with a game inside of that project. I found a Java development game framework called `LibGDX`. When I was trying to use it, I got several problems. First, Inside a class that extends `ApplicationAdapter` in the `core` module, I'm unable to call all of the Java object like `String`, error said:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'String'
```

The second problem is all of the `Gdx` object having some errors like:

```
Cannot access java.lang.Object
```

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Texture(java.lang.String)'
```

The weird thing: with the second problem I can still installing and running it.
I have been trying to fix the `Gradle` but it doesn't work. This is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"


    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "TestGame"
        gdxVersion = '1.10.0'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.12'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.3'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        testImplementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"

    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"


    }
}
```

The Class:

```
public class TestGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Perhaps this is a basic question, but this `LibGDX` stuff is somewhat Greek to me.

Comment: I suggest using this app to create you’re project. It’s better than the official setup app. You’ll have fewer issues. https://github.com/tommyettinger/gdx-liftoff

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and this solution worked for me. Go to your gradle.properties file. Write
`org.gradle.java.home=C\:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.12`
or wherever your JDK folder is located like org.gradle.java.home=(wherever your jdk FOLDER is). I also found this post online that shows a similar problem but it is specifically for IntelliJ and maybe Android Studio so this might not work for you. This solution might not work if you are not using the libGDX setup since it is only tested on that. I am also very new to libGDX. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207039495-Cannot-resolve-symbol-String-. This post is old though

Answer (score 0):

Yes-yes I had been spent two days resolving this issue.
In my case, I just updated Android Studio and all works well.